# Jquery - 'If Lightbox 1 is open, and press Right, change to lightbox 2' - 2 IF Statements

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement

So I've got 4 main icons on my webpage, and when you click one, a lightbox pops up. When you click off, the lightbox retreats. When You click the 2nd Icon, lightbox 2 appears etc.

What I'm trying to do, is set up the jQuery to also change between the 4 lightboxes when the users press left and right.

To do this I need 2 If Statements for each action.

I need 'IF LIGHTBOX ONE IS OPEN (DISPLAY: BLOCK)' and user presses RIGHT Button, close lightbox one, and display lightbox 2.

I need 'IF LIGHTBOX TWO IS OPEN (DISPLAY: BLOCK)' and user presses RIGHT Button, close lightbox two, and display lightbox 3.

I need 'IF LIGHTBOX TWO IS OPEN (DISPLAY: BLOCK)' and user presses LEFT Button, close lightbox two, and display lightbox 1.

ETC.

Here is My Jquery so far, I haven't included my attempt at how to do this because I don't think I'm getting close. Thanks

//Main screen lightbox functions --

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

            $('.lightboxgo').click(function(){
            $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 600, 'linear');
            $('.lightbox').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .lightbox').css('display', 'block');
            })

        $('.lightboxgo2').click(function(){
            $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 600, 'linear');
            $('.lightbox2').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .lightbox2').css('display', 'block');
            })

        $('.lightboxgo3').click(function(){
            $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 600, 'linear');
            $('.lightbox3').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .lightbox3').css('display', 'block');
            })

        $('.lightboxgo4').click(function(){
            $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 600, 'linear');
            $('.lightbox4').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .lightbox4').css('display', 'block');
            })

        $('.close').click(function(){
            close_box();
        });

        $('.backdrop').click(function(){
            close_box();
        });


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        close_box();
    }
});

//Function created to hide lightbox and backdrop --

function close_box()
{

        $('.backdrop, .lightbox, .lightbox2, .lightbox3, .lightbox4, .portfolioimage1').animate({'opacity':'.0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
            $('.backdrop, .lightbox, .lightbox2, .lightbox3, .lightbox4, .portfolioimage1').css('display', 'none');
            });
}
});
```

Comment: wat you ask for it is basic behavior of lightbox script, if you followed instruction. http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#how-to-use

Comment: Good Point. I didn't actually use lightbox. I did the jquery myself, I just called it a lightbox.... And I can't rob the js from that because it's done in a way that I cannot understand :S I'm such a novice with Jquery...

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify this logic a bit by abstracting this a bit.

1. have a function that opens a light box that takes a parameter thats a jquery element of the light box to be opened and also have one that closes it.
2. save a variable that holds all the light box clickable elements and use the jquery data- api to bind the button to the light box it opens also save a variable that is a class name for whatever is open.
3. add a click listener to the light box buttons that looks at what was clicked and opens a light box based on that (using the data api) by calling that open function. Also set up your click listners for the close and backdrop elements that close a light box and have them close the open one by using that class name for whatever is open
4. whenever you open a lightbox, add key listeners and switch light boxes using the jquery prev() and next() functions to switch between light box elements then you close whatever's open and open the next() or prev() ones and whenever you close, remove that key listener

Make sense?

This probably isn't perfect but it illustrates that i'm saying in code:

```
$(function(){
    var lightBoxes = $(".lightbox");// 1 class that every lightbox has
    var openClass = "lightboxOpen";// class for when you have an open lightbox only 1 at a time will have this
    function close_box($el){

        $el.removeClass(openClass);//remove the class when closing it
        //code to close specific light box using $el to refer to the lightbox
        removeKeyDownListener();//define a function to remove the listeners when you close
    }

    function openLightbox($el){
       $el.addClass(openClass);//add the open class when opening
       //code to open lightbox using $el to refer to the specific one to be opened
       addKeyDownListeners()//define a function to listen to key listeners
    }

    function addKeyDownListener(){
       $(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
           var openBox = $('.'+ openClass);
           close_box($(openBox);//close the open box first
           if(e.keyCode == [key for right arrow]){
               var nextItem = openBox.next();//this will work if your lightbox elements are setup as siblings(under the same parent at the same level of nesting)
               openLightBox(nextItem);
           }

           if(e.keyCode == [key for left arrow]){
               var prevItem = openBox.prev();//this will work if your lightbox elements are setup as siblings(under the same parent at the same level of nesting)
               openLightBox(prevItem);
           }
       });
    }

    function removeKeyDownListeners(){
        $(document).unbind('keydown');//remove all key down listeners
    }

    lightBoxes.click(function(){
        var item = $(this);// capture the specific one clicked on
        var lightboxItem = item.data('lightboxel');//use the data attribute to bind the button to its lightbox ex <div class="lightboxgo4 lightbox" data-lightboxel=".lightbox4"></div>
        openLightbox($(lightboxItem));//define a function that opens the lightbox
    }); 

    $('.close, .backdrop').click(function(){
       close_box($('.' + openClass));//close the lightbox with the open class
    });

});
```